# Is there a way to loop copying values in R?

Tags: r, loops, copying

I am working with a really messy dataset for my master's thesis and I need some help with copying values from one column to other columns.

What I need to do is the following:

1. I need the value from row 1 to be copied to the column price_close in the same row.
2. I need the value from row 2 to be copied to the column price_high in row 1
3. I need the value from row 3 to be copied to the column price_low in row 1
4. I need the value from row 4 to be copied to the column price_open in row 1
5. I need the value from row 5 to be copied to the column shares_outstanding in row 1

This needs to be done for all companies and for all dates. Hence, I need to do the same procedure for the next company. Meaning:

1. I need the value from row+5 to be copied to the column price_close in the same row.
2. I need the value from row+6 to be copied to the column price_high in row+5
3. I need the value from row+7 to be copied to the column price_low in row+5
4. I need the value from row+8 to be copied to the column price_open in row+5
5. I need the value from row+9 to be copied to the column shares_outstanding in row+5

The dataset is too large to be able to do this by hand. However, I imagine that this is possible using a loop in R, since the "copying" follows the same pattern throughout the dataset. If that's the case, I would really appreciate some guidance to solve this problem. Thanks!

In the picture attached, you can see how my data looks like.

[image: Snippet of my dataset]

Comment: Please post a non-image version of your data, preferably the output of `dput(yourdata)`

Comment: Yeah you don't want to do it like this, but use a combination of `separate` and `pivot_wider`, both from the `tidyr` package. If you share some data using `dput(head(your_data, 20))` we can show you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is converting your data from "long format to wide format". Searching that phrase will turn up lots of ways to accomplish this in R. Here's one, you could use `pivot_wider()` from tidyr, like this:

(edited to use `separate()` as suggested by @Axeman)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  separate(col = "variable", into = c("company", "metric"), sep = " - ") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("company", "date"), names_from = "metric", values_from = "value")
#>     company       date Price Close High Price Price Low Opening price
#> 1 Company 1 2022-01-01         5.5        6.0       5.0           5.0
#> 2 Company 2 2022-01-01         3.5        7.0       8.0           1.0
#> 3 Company 1 2022-01-02         5.4        5.9       4.9           4.8
#>   Common Shares Outstanding
#> 1                      1000
#> 2                      5000
#> 3                      1000
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame(variable = c("Company 1 - Price Close",
                              "Company 1 - High Price",
                              "Company 1 - Price Low",
                              "Company 1 - Opening price",
                              "Company 1 - Common Shares Outstanding",
                              "Company 2 - Price Close",
                              "Company 2 - High Price",
                              "Company 2 - Price Low",
                              "Company 2 - Opening price",
                              "Company 2 - Common Shares Outstanding",
                              "Company 1 - Price Close",
                              "Company 1 - High Price",
                              "Company 1 - Price Low",
                              "Company 1 - Opening price",
                              "Company 1 - Common Shares Outstanding"),
                 date = c(rep("2022-01-01", 10), rep("2022-01-02", 5)),
                 value = c(5.5, 6, 5, 5, 1000,
                           3.5, 7, 8, 1, 5000,
                           5.4, 5.9, 4.9, 4.8, 1000))
```

Created on 2022-05-23 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)

Comment: Hi

Thank you for taking the time to help. I really appreciate it.

When I am trying to pivot data from long to wide format I get an error message:

Error in `vec_init()`:
`n` must be a single number, not an integer `NA`.

Warning message:
In nrow * ncol: NAs produced by integer overflow.

What does that imply?

It's my first time posting a question here, so if I am not answering or posting the question correctly, I am sorry in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: Based on my understanding, this implies that `pivot_wider()` is attempting to define an integer that is larger than R is able to store. It is possible that you simply have too much data to use my suggested approach, but what's more likely is that your output, based on how you defined the pivot, is TOO wide. Look carefully at the example data I posted. I define a metric field and company field, and use these fields as scaffolding for the new format. Are you able to do that with your data? How many unique `metric` do you have? How many unique `company` + `date` combinations? Post your data! :)

Comment: You are welcome here! The easiest way to post/share your data to the site is by editing your question to include the results of `dput(YOURDATAFRAME)`. If there's too much data, you could share a subset `dput(YOURDATAFRAME[1:100,])`

Comment: Yes, I managed to define company and metrics successfully using your method. Didn't know how to do that before, thanks for educating me ;)

My data consists of daily stock prices from 2002-04-01 until 2022-04-01 of around 730 companies. So, I have 5 metrics for each date for all 730 companies. So at the moment, with everything in the current format, I have 19 522 800 obs.

What I want is for the data to look exactly like the one in the example you provided.

How do I post my data? Could you see the picture I attached? Tried using dput but the output from that was super long.

Comment: Saw your comment now. I'll try to subset the output :)

Comment: Hi Skaqqs, 

The solution you provided worked perfectly when also using separate ().  You have saved me so many hours of trying to figure this out by myself. I appreciate it a lot!

Also thanks @Axeman for the contribution!!

Have a nice day! :)